# UIView used as separator messed up my constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I used UIView as separator for my UITableViewCells but on removal of the cell I didn't use any method to delete the UIView too. I don't know if the UIView is removed when I remove the cells but some of my buttons constraints on other UIViewControllers messed up.

For those buttons I used a method to bind them to the keyboard (stick to bottom when keyboard is not active, stick to keyboard when keyboard is active) which worked perfect (tested it for a week) until I added this uiview as separator method. Despite deleting the method, my constraints are still f*kd up and I get this in the debugger

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000029d6a0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.width == 320   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000296e40 UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6040007a0540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000296df0 UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6040007a0540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029bcb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0.width == 414   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000292e30 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6040007a0540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000293100 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6040007a0540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000296df0 UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6040007a0540'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-10-11 10:37:32.670217+0300 Expense Manager[2853:71957] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000029d290 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.midY == 540   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000029d5b0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA'.height == 56   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000294d70 V:[UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000029bbc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0.height == 736   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000029b990 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UITransitionView:0x7f9a0770b780 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x604000294d70 V:[UIButton:0x7f9a07538760'ADAUGA']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9a07640bb0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Here is a picture. Instead of that button being binded to left, right and bottom, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFlfP.jpg)

Is there any method I can do to delete those UIViews that I created or what can I do to get my constraints back to normal.

Comment: add your screen where you facing issue.'

Comment: click on 'this'